# Nook Color - Honeycomb ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, 3.0-honeycomb, nook-color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Is there a stable Honeycomb ROM for the Nook Color that can be installed on the phone's memory  and not exclusively run off an SD card?

I am currently running CM 7.1 and like the stability I get but might be willing to sacrifice it to try out HC.

Comment: Do note that any HC "rom" you find will be an emulator based rom since HC source was never released.